# What's the difference between quantize() and str.format()?

Tags: python, django, string, quantization

I don't mean what's the technical difference, but rather, what's the faster/more logical or Pythonic, etc. way to do this:

```
    def __quantized_price(self):
        TWOPLACES = Decimal(10) ** -2
        return self.price.quantize(TWOPLACES)
```

or

```
    def __formatted_price(self):
        TWOPLACES = Decimal(10) ** -2
        return '{0:.2f}'.format(self.price)
```

They seem to be exactly the same so I'm just wondering why they created quantize when

Comment: Ummm... The only thing that matters is the technical difference, since they do completely different things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Decimal.quantize` returns a new `Decimal` that has a different value.

`''.format()` formats a string.

In this particular case printing the result yields the same output. Other than that they are totally different operations returning totally different types.

Comment: Oh, so 5.00 is a different value than 5?

Comment: Yes, they are very different. Do you remember physics? A value of 5 with three significant digits (+/- 0.005) is not the same as a value of 5 with a single significant digit (+/- 0.5).